# Extract alphanumeric string from line Batch Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, adb

I am working on a batch file that will connect the device selected automatically. This is the beginning of my script:

```
echo This is the list of connected devices:
adb devices -l | findstr "[0-9]"|find /N " "
set /P device= Select the device you would like to connect to:
```

This is the output in Windows command prompt:

> ```
> [1]350800651       device asdsffas
> [2]07ea9b921       device iwoequeo
> ```

What I am trying now, is to get just the ID number from the device (`350800651` or `07ea9b921`) that would be the one from the selected row (`1` or `2` in the example). Any ideas of how I can do it? I have tried with `findstr` + regex but it always gives me back the full line...

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=] " %%i in ('adb devices -l ^| findstr "[0-9]"|find /N " "') do echo %%i`

Comment: `findstr` is a tool for searching lines but not to extract portions of them. Anyway, your search string `[0-9]` is not quite adequate; I'd suggest something like `^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\>` (at the beginning of a line, there must be 9 alpha-numeric characters, word-separated from the rest; perhaps add the `/I` switch; I know this is still not perfect due to poor design of `findstr` (it might still match unwanted characters like `²`, `à`, etc.), but it's often a good compromise rather than having to provide a full char. list `[012...9abc...z]`).

Comment: ok, thank so much! I just applied those changes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a linked answer as per the now closed question link.

There however is another simple workaround... not the best, but might work for you.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=] " %%i in ('adb devices -l ^| findstr "[0-9]"|find /N " "') do (
   set /p "result=Do you want to select device %%i [Y/N]: "
   if /i "!result!"=="Y" "set device=%%i" & goto next
)
:next
echo do something else here with %device%
```